# send mail from ar_mailer is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ar-mailer

I have this task:

```
task :send_emails => :environment do
  Dir.chdir(Rails.root)
  ActionMailer::ARSendmail.run(['-o'])
end
```

I try to run it as a cronjob, or in console. The emails table is full, but no emails are coming out.

The query that I get in the log is very strange:

1. Eventhough I run production mode, the log is created in development.log
2. The query that I get there is:

   SELECT `emails`.* FROM `emails` WHERE (last_send_attempt > 0 and created_on < **'2015-07-12** 23:36:49')

But today is 2015-07-19. Why does it go to an older date?

It seems that in the query it gets the emails, it says:

> ar_sendmail: found 1000 emails to send

but it does nothing.

???

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the log has not used an incorrect date.  But rather, you are looking at an old entry.

Comment: No. I can see the hours that I pressed "enter" key when trying to invoke it from the console.

Answer (score 1):

I too think that you are looking at the wrong log or the log is not working.